# Accidentally Vacuumed some asbestos duct tape, should I throw out the vacuum?

Tags: hvac, asbestos, vacuum

I had just finished a project where I had encapsulated some asbestos duct tape. Don't worry I did it all by the book: I used an air scrubber the entire time I was in there, had a full Tyvek suit on with a respirator, sealed off the room with polyvinyl plastic, and bought all the correct encapsulating materials I needed such as the repair wrap, canvas wrap, and paint.

In all the job went really well and I didn't disturb any then. There was one piece of the tape that somehow fell off over the years so I wet it down and bagged it up. Finally, after I finished the project I let the scrubber run for a while and did a good vacuuming with a HEPA filter and bag. Once everything was cleaned up and got started on the second part of my project I decided I needed to clean again after things got messy.

This time I was vacuuming and something got stuck to my vacuum and it was asbestos tape that somehow got missed. (it wasn't even where the duct run was?) Now what should I do? I just bought the vacuum and am frustrated that after all that I missed a little piece of tape. Can it be cleaned somehow? or is it garbage?

Comment: Change the filter and clean.  Unless the tape jam something and the vacuum started smoking.  It is good to be concerned about asbestos, but not to worry obsessively over such a tiny amount.

Comment: Give it a thorough cleaning and you're good. Asbestos does most its damage from repeated exposure, day in and day out like in a factory making the stuff. Asbestos fibers are naturally occurring and you probably had housands in your lungs before you even started.

Comment: Ok, I'll be careful to be safe as I clean it. It was a tiny piece of tape and I'm sure only a very tiny bit of dust went into the vacuum. Do you think running it for a while outside is a good idea once cleaned?

Comment: It's easy enough to do that so night as well.

Comment: So are all trip and fall hazards eliminated in the house? Stairways have solid handrails? Is the range and dryer on a 4-wire connection or GFCI? Are all the kitchen, bathroom, laundry, basement, garage outlets GFCI?  Do you have AFCI breakers on older wiring?  Smoke, CO, radon detectors all up to snuff? Because [humans are not very good at assessing risks](https://www.wired.com/2007/03/security-matters0322/), and in particular they tend to wildly overblow risk of asbestos, because of the hype. The hype exists for a reason, it isn't safety.

Comment: You're fine, asbestos isn't a poison, it's an irritant, affected people with industrial exposure to asbestos dust every day. The tiny bit you "MIGHT" have been exposed to won't hurt you at all.

Comment: Thanks for the information George. Do you think it's safe to clean the vacuum or should I toss it?

Answer (score 0):

According to CDC and NIOSH you can use an N95 or N100.

Obviously N95 is the minimum standard, not the maximum standard. Refer to the [guideline](https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/npptl/topics/respirators/disp_part/default.html).

- Put on an N-95 mask. Put on coveralls.
- Clean up the inside of the vacuum. Wash or replace filter is vacuums.
- Do it outside over a trash back (large 55gal) split open.
- Once cleaned take vacuum out and let parts air dry out of any mess you had in a clean area.
- Take the plastic where you cleaned up vacuum, cover it inside to incapsulate and throw away.
- Peel your mask off without gloves, putting finger under your mask not to touch outside. Throw it with the other stuff. Then dust off coveralls- the  peel off your coveralls inside out to trap asbestos. (Throw in laundry machine and wash overalls in high water setting by themselves.

I'm retired from Public Health, this is the basics save the vacuum. They cost too much. You're ok.

Comment: NO! DO NOT DO THAT! An N95 mask does not /cannot be used to protect against asbestos! You retired from public health and don't know n95 doesn't protect against asbestos? By wearing this mask, you have a false sense of security. I know, it's long term exposure but can't give a false sense of security.

Comment: N95 mask doesn't protect from very much at all. Also, you're suggesting that the overalls be washed in the washing machine? Isn't that now contaminating the washing machine, spreading instant death to all the other clothes that ever touch the washer? Based on the current state of the "Public Health" apparatus in the world today, this sounds about right. :(

Comment: Thanks guys, I have a real respirator for asbestos, so I was just going to use that. and my tyvek suit. Didnt think about the fact that the comment was wrong. I was mainly looking at the information for cleaning the vacumm